# How can I get user URL by id

Tags: custom-post-types, user-meta

I am using custom post types, and I have a problem getting the author URL to his profile.

I can get the author ID using:

```
$authers_interviewdoctor = get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'authers_interviewdoctor' , true );
```

However, I need to get the link to his profile, such as:

```
www.example.com/author/admin
```

Comment: have you seen `the_author_meta`

Comment: its not get me user url

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`get_author_posts_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url) to get the author's link.

Answer (score 0):

To get the Author URL, you have to use:

```
<?php global $authordata; ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( false, $authordata->ID, $authordata->user_nicename ); ?>" title="<?php printf( __( 'View all posts by %s', 'your-theme' ), $authordata->display_name ); ?>">
     <?php the_author(); ?>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside the WordPress loop:

```php
$auther_url = get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) );
```

Use `$auther_url` in link href.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $author = get_queried_object();
    echo get_author_posts_url( false, $author->user_nicename ); 
?>
```

Comment: Could you [edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/260560/edit) ( by clicking the [edit button above](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/260560/edit) ) and add in more detail on how this solves the issue and where you would put this code, please?

Answer (score 0):

To get Author `URL` you can use this code snippet. Author URL will be retrieve by ID.

```
<ul class="blog-meta">
   <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta("ID"))); ?>">Admin Name</a></li>
</ul>
```